# How to fetch data from a third party API in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I am currently trying to make a `request` to a third party library in my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and work with this data (it really has to run over a Web API template).

That means I'm importing data from another API.

Unfortunately I don't know how to tell my application to make a call.
I would have expected the `Task` to run automatically when the application starts. Unfortunately this is not the case.

I first wanted to test whether this works at all when the application is started. Later, I would build in a scheduler, which sends requests accordingly.

It should be possible, right?

It would be great if someone could tell me as well if it's possible to put the URL "localhost:xxx/" in the constructor somehow, but still not get any dependency injection errors with `AddScoped`.

I use `Flurl.Http` to make Http Requests.

If it is important. My `program.cs` is in a console application and DataImport in an empty project

Unfortunately, I am relatively new to the ASP.NET world and I hope that the question is not too unprofessional. Otherwise I apologize. It's kind of hard to google for a problem like this and find something

```
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;

public class DataImport
{
    private readonly Service service;

    public DataImport(Servie service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Data>> ImportData()
    {
        var data = await "localhost:xxx/".AppendPathSegment("data").GetJsonAsync<DataDto[]>();
        return _service.Add(data.Select(it => new DatoDtoToData(it)));
    }
}
```

`program.cs`:

```
builder
.Services
... Service Injections
....
.AddScoped<DataImport>()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246677/discussion-on-question-by-maxfromgermany-how-to-fetch-data-from-a-third-party-ap).

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to look into Azure Functions.

Have a look at Microsoft's [Introduction to Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview#scenarios). In the *Scenarios* section we can read.

> The following are a common, but by no means exhaustive, set of scenarios for Azure Functions.
>
> | If you want to... | then... |
> | --- | --- |
> | Build a web API | Implement an endpoint for your web applications using the HTTP trigger |
> | ... |  |
> | Build a serverless workflow | Chain a series of functions together using durable functions |
> | ... |  |
> | Run scheduled tasks | Execute code on pre-defined timed intervals |
> | ... |  |

---

I really think this could work well for you because:

1. You can run/host it locally or host it in Azure.
2. It's very easy to start with. Microsoft's tutorials are:

   - [Quickstart: Create your first C# function in Azure using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio?tabs=in-process), and
   - [Quickstart: Create a C# function in Azure using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process)
3. It supports multiple ways of triggering your functions. There are over 20 tiggers; with 2 of the most relevant for you should be:

   - [Azure Functions HTTP trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example)
   - [Timer trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

---

Comment: nice thank you I see for the first time. Could this also be used to solve my problem explicitly, or is this a completely different approach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say "completely different approach" and "explicitly"?

Comment: I can use it i a web api project as well, or?

Comment: Can you use it **in** a web api project? It may be possible but you're swimming against the current then and there isn't a reason to do it like that. Normally you would have a separate projects for functions. Note that a function with a http trigger *is* an api endpoint.